# Streaming data into Go template? (while loops in templates)

Tags: loops, go, while-loop, streaming, go-templates

I'm trying to make my Go program stream data from stdin into a template.

Before, it read all the data into memory,
and the template `range`s through it:

```golang
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
d := make([]string, 0)
for scanner.Scan() {
    d = append(d, scanner.Text())
}

txt := `
{{- range . -}}
    {{- .}}
{{end}}`

template.
    Must(template.New("").Parse(txt)).
    Execute(os.Stdout, d)
```

This is what I want to do,
except that there are no `for`/`while` loops in Go's templates:

```golang
d := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

txt := `
{{- while .Scan /* this does not exist */ -}}
    {{- .Text}}
{{end}}`

template.
    Must(template.New("").Parse(txt)).
    Execute(os.Stdout, d)
```

This is my current workaround:

```golang
d := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

fnmap := template.FuncMap{
    "loop": func(n int) []bool { return make([]bool, n) },
}
txt := `
{{- range loop 999999999 -}}
    {{- if not $.Scan -}}
        {{- break -}}
    {{- end -}}
    {{- $.Text}}
{{end}}`

template.
    Must(template.
        New("").
        Funcs(fnmap).
        Parse(txt)).
    Execute(os.Stdout, d)
```

However, it seems quite inelegant and inefficient
to allocate an enormous, unused slice, just to loop through.

Is there a better way to do this,
perhaps more similar to my second example?

Answer (score 0):

Move the loop into your Go code by splitting the template into prefix, loop body and suffix.

```
    txt := `
{{define "prefix"}}
   before
{{end}}
{{define "loop"}}
   {{- $.Text -}}
{{end}}
{{define "suffix"}}
   after
{{end}}`

t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(txt))
t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "prefix", nil)
for scanner.Scan() {
    t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "loop", scanner)
}
t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "suffix", nil)
```

[Run an example on the play ground](https://go.dev/play/p/gG2BeUrAkWI)